# What is the correct name of this filter?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, print-design, style-identification, filter

Normally, this is what would you would see if you magnified older newspaper images printed in color. (check the background of the attached image)

What is this filter called?
How can I recreate this filter in GIMP or Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: Scott basically covered it but here is a nice video tutorial about the process. http://www.lynda.com/Photoshop-tutorials/Using-Color-Halftone-filter/115429/134517-4.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Halftone effects in Gimp come with quite some variety for adjusting to personal needs. From the *Filters > Distorts > Newsprint...* settings we can see that the resuting halftone image is better than the one posted in the question. Therefore we probably have to add additional filters. That's where creativity is asked, as there is not a prebuilt singular filter to do this.

Now this is how I tried to recreate the image above in **Gimp**:

1. Add color noise (*Filter > Noise > RGB Noise* set to `0.20` for R, G, and B)
2. Add halftone effect (*Filter > Distorts > Newsprint*) with the following settings:

   - Cell size `3`
   - Separate to `RGB`
   - `Diamond` at angle `35,0` (channels locked)
   - Oversampling `8`
3. Add some blur (which might have come from down-scaling of the image in question)

   [image]
   <sup>Image source: [Wikimedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/Space_Shuttle_Challenger_%2804-04-1983%29.JPEG)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

**Photoshop** `Filter > Pixelate > Color Halftone...`

In Illustrator you can use the Photoshop Effects (in the Effects menu) for the same thing. There are third-party plug ins for Illustrator to apply halftone effects which work a bit better than the built in raster effect. [Phantasm](http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/phantasm/) is a great one.

Comment: Thank you, I actually need to get this to work with GIMP, but Photoshop would be an alternative. GIMP has a Distorts > Newsprint effect, but the pattern is different.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Gimp.

Comment: "the pattern is different" reads like you aren't aware of the adjustable settings of the newsprint filter in GIMP. What have you tried there to get this pattern?